# Writefile, Readfile code error for bad sectors

Tags: windows, winapi

I use `WriteFile` or `ReadFile` for a volume read/write on Windows. What is the error code returned by `WriteFile` or `ReadFile` if it tries to read or write on a bad sector?

Comment: Is this C++? Please tag the language you are using.

Comment: @BaliC It doesn't matter what language is used. Windows doesn't know. It returns the same error code for all languages.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Ah right, I didn't know that. I thought it would look clearer if it was tagged though incase it was language specific.

Comment: I think it's very hard to answer this. I would not be surprised if there were a variety of error codes that could be returned.

Comment: ERROR_CRC ought to be used to signal drive errors.  No idea if that's still accurate, I haven't used floppy disks in a very long time.  Modern disk drives repair themselves.

Comment: Please write it as answer Hans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The underlying [NTSTATUS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc704588.aspx) code should be `STATUS_DEVICE_DATA_ERROR` (0xC000009C):

> There are bad blocks (sectors) on the hard disk.

Which will [map](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/113996) to `ERROR_CRC` (23).